# Weight distribution during ski carving

Tags: skiing

I consider myself an intermediate skier and during my progress with the sport two of the rules that I followed were:

1. You should aim to move your weight forward and press forward on the skies (avoid leaning back in general, except in deep snow).
2. Your weight should be on the lower ski ( or the outside ski during a turn).

However I have recently watched some Youtube videos on the topic of ski carving, such as tutorials and tips and what I have seen in those videos conflicts with the rules above. I present two images , taken from such a video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ElOhJyNPjUE&t=57s).

In the first image the skier positioned his body in such a way that the majority of his body mass is behind the shoes. In the second image the skier positioned his body in such a way that the majority of his body mass is to the right of his right foot (which is the inside foot, as he is turning right).

So my questions are:

1. How do you press forward on the skies, if your body is so far back, like in the case of Image 1?
2. How do you put weight on your outside ski if your body is so far to the right in the case of Image 2?
3. Are those two rules that I stated different when skiing at higher speeds?

Image 1

[image: Image 1]

Image 2

[image: Image 2]

Comment: What makes you think that the centre of gravity in pic 1 is rear of the legs? Seems to me that it would be forward of the shins, but hard to tell as the are turning and in a non-standard squat position as a consequence.

Comment: Well he seams to be pretty far back for what I am used to, or maybe its just the angle of the picture.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Stack Exchange requires just one question per post, however the three you have all stem from the same misunderstanding so I'll try to help.

Your two rules still work at speed. Specifically for those two photos, as that may  help you:

Picture 1 has the skier still with the weight forwards - the photo is a bit deceptive, but you can see how the ski is flexing.

In picture 2, the apparent weight is still on the outside ski. The only reason the skier is not falling over is because they are in a fast turn so the centripetal force is pushing their body outwards (similar to how you need to lean in to the centre of a merry go round at speed - if you stand straight up you will fall outwards)

So your q1 is not relevant, as the weight is not far back, q2 is just related to centripetal force, and for q3, yes, just follow the same rules.

Comment: Thank you! Glad to know i am doing things the right way. I probably have the same stance, just haven't seen myself from an another view.